# Integrating over a region where a function of two variables is less than some value

Tags: integration

Say I have

$$
f(x,y)=e^{b(x^2+y^2)}
$$

and I want to integrate over the region where $f(x,y)<a$. What is the best way to work out the limits on the integral (one of them being a function of $x$ or $y$)?

($a$ and $b$ are constants)

Comment: take $\ln(a)/b > x^2 + y^2$, which is a circle.

Comment: so if a convert to polars it would be easier?

Comment: @AlexanderGiles yes. Generally any function depending only on the sum $x^2 + y^2$ in two dimensions can be seen as dependent on $r^2$ in polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

The task is precisely to find
$$f^{-1}((-\infty,a)) = \{(x,y) \in\mathbb R^2 : e^{b(x^2+y^2)}<a\} =: S$$
Assuming $a>0$ you have
$$S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: x^2 + y^2 < \frac{\ln a}b\}$$
And thus the set is given by
$$S = B_{\sqrt{\frac{\ln a}b}}(0)$$
(The open ball with radius $\sqrt{\frac{\ln a}b}$ around the origin). If $a\ge 0$, $S = \emptyset$.

---

For limits of integration I suggest
$$\begin{align*}
\int_S f(x,y) d(x,y) & = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\sqrt{\frac{\ln a}b}} r e^{br^2} dr d\phi \\
& = 2\pi \int_0^{\sqrt{\frac{\ln a}b}} re^{br^2} dr \\
& = 2\pi \left[ \frac1{2b} e^{br^2} \right]_{r=0}^{\sqrt{\frac{\ln a}b}} = \frac{\pi}b (a-1)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: cool thanks for this

Comment: @AlexanderGiles Happy to help. If this solved your question, please mark it as answered. If not, feel free to ask for further clarification :)

Answer (score 1):

You want the region for which $e^{b(x^2+y^2)} < a$.

Taking the natural log of both sides gives $b(x^2+y^2) < \ln a$, or $x^2 + y^2 < \frac{\ln a}{b}.$

This is the interior of a circle with radius $\sqrt{\frac{\ln a}{b}}$ centered at the origin.

Comment: ok got it cheers